# How to put all the TreeNodes from LogicalPlan in the list

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I am solving one problem where spark 3.0.1 cuts my execution plan if I apply the toJSON method to it:

```
  //spark 3.0.1
val myDf: DataFrame = ???
val myPersistDf = myDf.persist
val plan: LogicalPlan = myPersistDf.queryExecution.optimizedPlan
  //toJSON method cuts down my plan
val jsonPlan = plan.toJSON
```

My execution plan is being cut, so I want to work around this problem. The Logical Plan is stored in the spark as a tree from the TreeNode. Is there a way to get a list of all Tree Nodes of the execution plan?
For example, such a list:
`Seq[TreeNode[_]]`

Comment: I found changes concerning my problem. Can I use them in my custom code by saving the current version of spark? https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/32557/files/6b836cc31619f260219f154686d8a8198a48a706

Comment: @OneCricketer, Can I use these changes while keeping the current version of spark?